# Clash of clans Api (developers) with Vagrant

Tags: api

I would like access to the clash of clans API (developer.clashofclans.com) in my Vagrant box but i have an accessDenied "Invalid authorization".

This is because my ip is not allowed but what ip i do put ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you running on localhost, you should put your NAT, you can see it here: http://whatismyipaddress.com/

Also, an easy way to know which IP you should put you can do this trick:

- Create a api key with stupid ip address
- Make a curl request with this token:

  curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "authorization: Bearer " "https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/clans?name=test"

And you will get a response like this:

```
{"reason":"accessDenied.invalidIp","message":"Invalid authorization: API key does not allow access from IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"}
```

Now you know for sure what ip the API is expecting from you :)

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine at home but in my work my computer ip not worked. Thanks !